# Recording time between new questions/page loads in a survey

Tags: google-chrome, browser, timing, survey, data-collection

I have an academic survey which needs to record the time spent on each question. All of the questions are on separate pages. I've just discovered that QuestionPro, which I'm using, cannot do this (or at least won't allow it in the package I have access to). 
I will need to record these timings for each person who takes the survey (which will take place in a controlled lab) and keep each person's separate.

Is there any way of recording this data? I'm open to anything at this stage, as long as I can achieve it in a few days.

Comment: limesurvey have this directly https://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_settings#Notification_.26_data_management , can be installed on your server (Free Software)

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro your question description does not match with the question title. An I understood ,

If you want to capture the timings for each question and for all users. It is be possible using programming logic and some modification in db design. You can add an extra field for time, which you have to update at the time of transition from one question to another in the same table where you are capturing answers. And at the start of question you can run a timer.

If you want to measure the time to load a page at client side. you can go with some java script libs.
One of which I know is [Navigation Timing](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/). You can take help from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/#how) .

Hope you got it. If you have another question, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Sunil
Thank you for the response. I was trying to be specific in my title about what needed to be achieved - can you suggest something better? 
Have you any experience doing what you first suggested using QuestionPro, or would I be best to leave that?

Comment: Are you a developer? OR searching online ready made solution for Your need .

Comment: I certainly have experience in developing, and am willing to look outside ready made solutions.